# parse JSON keys preserving ordinality

Tags: postgresql, json, jsonb

I [had](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33731703/4709762) [heard](https://twitter.com/Xof/status/1489413786243006464) that in postgresql, the `json` type [preserves declared ordering](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-json.html#:%7E:text=The%20json%20data%20type%20stores%20an%20exact%20copy%20of%20the%20input%20text%2C%20which%20processing%20functions%20must%20reparse%20on%20each%20execution) unlike it's fully-parsed counterpart `jsonb`.

I want to get the ordinal position of each key in a document as supplied by the client. From [what I've tried](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=7c1cee2a69d5a6aace70bcb7301f951d&hide=31) though, this doesn't seem possible.

```sql
select *
from jsonb_path_query(
    '[{"foo":1},{"foo":2,"bar":3}]'::jsonb,
    '$.*'::jsonpath
) with ordinality
```

| jsonb_path_query | ordinality |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 |
| 3 | 2 |
| 2 | 3 |

The preceding query shows me leaf node value 3 at ordinal position 2 despite it being supplied as the third key, but there doesn't appear to be a `json_path_query` companion to `jsonb_path_query`.

Is there a built-in function to parse `json` keys? Or am I limited to either stricter `jsonb` or completely unconstrainted `text` parsing to extract this information?

Comment: There doesn't appear to be path support in `json`, but you can still use [other JSON functions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/functions-json.html), such as `json_array_elements` and `json_each` which might get you where you want. https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=9233fb60ffab1ff2ecb99a2f6e815f8c&hide=31

Comment: There is no relative posession in the JSON object for the object properties. If you need in definite ordering (if it makes sense) then you must use an array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`json_object_keys()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-json.html#FUNCTIONS-JSON-PROCESSING-TABLE:%7E:text=json_object_keys) can serve this use case.

Note in the [following example](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=de6ca591125129f3b568c1d8d2543052&hide=255) that the `jsonb` input reliably returns with sorted and deduplicated keys while `json` version gives us all keys as supplied by the client with correct ordinality.

```sql
select *
from json_object_keys('{"foo":2,"bar":3,"foo":4}'::json) 
    with ordinality
```

| json_object_keys | ordinality |
| --- | --- |
| foo | 1 |
| bar | 2 |
| foo | 3 |

```sql
select *
from jsonb_object_keys('{"foo":2,"bar":3,"foo":4}'::jsonb) 
    with ordinality
```

| json_object_keys | ordinality |
| --- | --- |
| bar | 1 |
| foo | 2 |